# .innerHTML and document.getElementById not displaying answer

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Does anyone know why this doesn't display the answer when I input 'rock' and 'scissors', respectively into the fields?

Code:

```js
function play(player1, player2) {
  let playerOneInput = document.getElementById("player1input").value;
  let playerTwoInput = document.getElementById("player2input").value;

  // Rock Options
  if (playerOneInput == "rock" && playerTwoInput == "scissors") {
    return (document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Player One wins.");
  } else if (playerOneInput == "rock" && playerTwoInput == "paper") {
    return (document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Player Two wins.");
  } else if (playerOneInput && playerTwoInput == "rock") {
    return (document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Tie.");
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Rock, Paper, Scissors</title>
  <script type="module" src="rockpapersci.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="ask" id="subscribe_frm" action="#">
    Player1: <input type="text" name="name" id="player1input" /> Player2: <input type="text" name="name" id="player2input" />
  </form>
  <input type="button" name="submit" value="Get Solution" onclick="play();" />
  <h1 id="answer"></h1>
</body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're missing the `}` at the end of the function.

Comment: check the console errors...

Comment: and double >/body>

Comment: And change the function signature to just **play()** instead of **play(player1, player2)**, matching the way you are calling it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like you've got a couple things wrong in your code.

Firstly, the `play` function should just have `play()` because you're not passing any arguments.

Secondly, you had a second `</body>` tag.

I've also added `label` tags to your HTML around `Player 1` and `Player 2`. This is best practice.

Lastly, I've finished off the scissors and paper portion.

```js
function play() {
  let playerOneInput = document.getElementById("player1input").value;
  let playerTwoInput = document.getElementById("player2input").value;

  // Rock
  if (playerOneInput == "rock" && playerTwoInput == "scissors") {
    return (document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Player One wins.");
  } else if (playerOneInput == "rock" && playerTwoInput == "paper") {
    return (document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Player Two wins.");
  } else if (playerOneInput && playerTwoInput == "rock") {
    return (document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Tie.");

    // Scissors
  } else if (playerOneInput == "scissors" && playerTwoInput == "rock") {
    return (document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Player Two wins.");
  } else if (playerOneInput == "scissors" && playerTwoInput == "paper") {
    return (document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Player One wins.");
  } else if (playerOneInput && playerTwoInput == "scissors") {
    return (document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Tie.");
  }

  // Paper
  else if (playerOneInput == "paper" && playerTwoInput == "rock") {
    return (document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Player Two wins.");
  } else if (playerOneInput == "paper" && playerTwoInput == "rock") {
    return (document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Player One wins.");
  } else if (playerOneInput && playerTwoInput == "paper") {
    return (document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Tie.");
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Rock, Paper, Scissors</title>
  <script type="module" src="rockpapersci.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Rock, Paper, Scissors</title>
  <script type="module" src="rockpapersci.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="ask" id="subscribe_frm">
    <!-- It's standard to have labels for your inputs. -->
    <label>Player1:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="player1input" />
    <!-- It's standard to have labels for your inputs. -->
    <label>Player2:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="player2input" />
  </form>
  <input type="button" name="submit" value="Get Solution" onclick="play();" />
  <h1 id="answer"></h1>
</body>

</html>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change some things:

- In HTML: `</BODY> </BODY>` had to be
- `function play() { ...}` without parameters.
- Close the function with `}`
- `if (playerOneInput && playerTwoInput == "rock")` is surely not what you want because this means value of playerOneInput must be true (what will be fullfilled if the user makes an input) and player2 has rock. You probably mean `if (playerOneInput == "rock" && playerTwoInput == "rock")` for both have rock choosen.

That there are missing the other cases without rock you know by yourself.

```js
function play() {
  let playerOneInput = document.getElementById("player1input").value;
  let playerTwoInput = document.getElementById("player2input").value;

console.log(playerOneInput, playerTwoInput);
  // Rock Options
  if (playerOneInput == "rock" && playerTwoInput == "scissors") {
    return (document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Player One wins.");
  } else if (playerOneInput == "rock" && playerTwoInput == "paper") {
    return (document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Player Two wins.");
  } else if (playerOneInput == "rock" && playerTwoInput == "rock") {
    return (document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Tie.");
  } 
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Rock, Paper, Scissors</title>
    <script type="module" src="rockpapersci.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name ="ask" id="subscribe_frm" action="#">
        Player1: <input type="text" name="name" id="player1input" />
        Player2: <input type="text" name="name" id="player2input" />
      </form> 
        <input type="button" name="submit" value="Get Solution" onclick="play();" />
        <h1 id="answer"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your function rewritten, I have only removed the parameters and also edited the last *else if*. And because you are writing the output to the document, the return statements are not necessary.

```
   function play() {
    let playerOneInput = document.getElementById("player1input").value;
    let playerTwoInput = document.getElementById("player2input").value;

    // Rock Options
    if (playerOneInput == "rock" && playerTwoInput == "scissors") {
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Player One wins.";
    } else if (playerOneInput == "rock" && playerTwoInput == "paper") {
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Player Two wins.";
    } else if (playerOneInput=="rock" && playerTwoInput == "rock") {
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = "Tie.";
    }
   }
```